# Python requests doesn't return same result as using browser

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, get, python-requests-html

I'm trying to use requests to basically scrape certain websites using requests & BeautifulSoup. The issue I'm having is that using requests `get` doesn't return the same result as it would if I used a browser. I know that requests doesn't support Javascript, but I'm trying to work around that. If I disable Javascript on Chrome and went to an Instagram profile, the web page returns (to the best of it's ability). It doesn't fully load, but it still includes basic details like a `<title></title>` that includes the username of the profile. However, when I send a GET request to the same URL in Python, the `<title></title>` attribute just returns with as `<title>Instagram</title>`

Why am I getting a different result?

For example, if I go to https://instagram.com/test on Chrome (with Javascript disabled) - I get a blank page, but I still get `<title>Zac (@test) • Instagram photos and videos</title>`, but if I use `requests.get("https://instagram.com/test")`, the return from the response would have `<title>Instagram</title>`

I've tried playing around with requests, and even tried switching to another lib like requests-html, but it always returns a different result than the browser.

Comment: Many sites can tell the difference between a legitimate browser request and a robot request and block or change the response given to the latter. Are you looking at the full HTML response to see what it contains? Don't assume it'll be the same as what's delivered to the browser, even if you have JS disabled.

Comment: Instagram is especially hostile towards users who access it while they are not logged in, even through a browser.  Sites like this use multiple methods to detect whether you are using a real browser or a programmatic request.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of scrapping Instagram you might need to use it API.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/